# calling a paint graphic after update in java

Tags: java

**Problem:**

After each key press of w, a, s or d the users x and y should change and the square is drawn to the x and y meaning that the graphic is not updating. My question is how do you update it ? I have tried using repaint everywhere and in every possible way and am starting to think that is not the issue. Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong or how to fix the issue. I am pretty new to Java so excuse me if i did a really simple mistake.

**Code:**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class KeyPressDrawing extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
    // define variables
    public static int user_x = 50;
    public static int user_y = 50;

    // init
    public KeyPressDrawing(String s){
        super(s);
        JPanel area = new JPanel();
        add(area);
        setSize(800, 800);
        setVisible(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setResizable(false);
    }

    // draw
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor (Color.black);
        // x position, y position, width length, height length
        g.fillRect(KeyPressDrawing.user_x, KeyPressDrawing.user_y, 50, 50);
        repaint();
}

    // check and change

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {}


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            System.out.println("Up");
            KeyPress.user_y -= 20;

        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            System.out.println("Left");
            KeyPress.user_x -= 20;

        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            System.out.println("Down");
            KeyPress.user_y += 20;

        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            System.out.println("Right");
            KeyPress.user_x += 20;
            }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new KeyPressDrawing("Control Panel");
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you supplied us with does not call the paint method at any point, that is needed.

Comment: I would probably look up game loops on google

Comment: @ItzBenteThePig and how is that done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code.  First, you are placing a JPanel as the primary widget in the JFrame but then you override the **paint** method of the JFrame itself and never delegate the calls to the super class so your JPanel won't be rendered.  What you likely want to do is move the drawing of the rectangle into a JPanel subclass that is your frame's main child widget.  Then, inside your **keyReleased** method you put in a call to the child widget's **repaint** method.  After each key release then the child panel will be told it needs to repaint.  Remove the **paint** method of the JFrame and use the default.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;


public class Sample extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
  public int user_x;
  public int user_y;
  public Canvas canvas;

  class Canvas extends JPanel{
    public Canvas() {
      setSize(getPreferredSize());
      Canvas.this.setBackground(Color.white);
      user_x = 10;
      user_y = 10;
    }

    @Override
    public final Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(600, 600);
    }

    @Override
    public final void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
      Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(0d, 0d, 100d, 100d);
      g2d.setColor(Color.red);
      g2d.translate(user_x, user_y);
      g2d.draw(circle);
      g2d.fill(circle);
    }
  }

  public Sample() {
    super("Sample");
    setSize(300, 300);
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
       public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
       public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {}
    });
    canvas = new Canvas();
    getContentPane().add(canvas);
    addKeyListener(this);
  }


// Implementation of java.awt.event.KeyListener

  public final void keyTyped(final KeyEvent keyEvent) {

  }

  public final void keyPressed(final KeyEvent keyEvent) {

  }

  public final void keyReleased(final KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
      System.out.println("Up");
      user_y -= 20;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
      System.out.println("Left");
      user_x -= 20;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
      System.out.println("Down");
      user_y += 20;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
      System.out.println("Right");
      user_x += 20;
    }
    //either canvas.repaint or just repaint for the frame will work here
    repaint();
  }

  public static final void main(final String[] args) {

     Sample f = new Sample();
     f.setVisible(true);
  }

} // Sample
```

Comment: If you put an example of what you are saying in a code example i will love you to the bone :p

Comment: <3 you are the best

Comment: I have a quick question, in your example is there a part that is constantly being looped cause I need to have a background process which is doing something

Comment: No there's no default loop.  If you want something like that you need to setup a separate thread that periodically calls an update method.  There are various timers available int he java libraries that can help with this.  If you do that, you can move the repaint call into the update method instead of the keyboard handler.  Keep in mind this update thread should only update state details, the primary graphics thread performs all graphics and event related functions.  I'd recommend you do some searching on Java 2D game loops/engines as that appears to be where you are heading.